# How do I install the Wifi drivers?

Tags: wireless, networking

I have been having problems with my WiFi connection on my DELL using Ubuntu as OS. I am new to the OS and trying to fix the issues I ended up un-installing the driver for the Network Controller.

```
description:   Network controller
product:       Wireless 7260
vendor:        Intel Corporation
physical id:   0
bus info:      pci@0000:08:00.0
version:       73
width:         64 bits
clock:         33MHz
```

Above the details of the controller. Could you please tell me how to re-install the drivers and what to do after so it will work properly (it was constantly disconnecting)?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No wireless with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 7260](http://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260)

Comment: It's actually a dupe of [bad wifi connection with Lenovo X240 under Ubuntu 14.04 — intel wireless 7260](http://askubuntu.com/questions/461849/bad-wifi-connection-with-lenovo-x240-under-ubuntu-14-04-intel-wireless-7260) - as are [Ubuntu 14.04 Intel 7260 AC Wireless driver does not work properly](http://askubuntu.com/questions/458974/ubuntu-14-04-intel-7260-ac-wireless-driver-does-not-work-properly) and [Intel 7260AC not working with Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456603/intel-7260ac-not-working-with-ubuntu-14-04).

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

did it turn back on? if so do:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwldvm
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

if not tell us how you uninstalled the driver.