# Wireless will not work with intel 7620

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a single board computer, a Jetson TK1.  I am using the intel 7620 pcie adapter for wireless connectivity.

I can connect wired with the board but wireless will not work.  I can create a wireless connection from the network dropdown, but the device will not let me enable wireless.

lspci shows:

```
00:00.0 PCI bridge: ...
01:00.0 Network Controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: ... TegraK1 PCIe Bridge (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet Controller: Realtek ...
```

sudo lspci -vvv -s 01:00.0 shows:

```
...
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

It seems the driver is available, detected, and bound to the hardware

The network manager gui does not show that WiFi is enabled and will not scan.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel seems to have a Firmware for their card available at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

The guy at [Ubuntu 14.04 Intel 7260 AC Wireless driver does not work properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458974/ubuntu-14-04-intel-7260-ac-wireless-driver-does-not-work-properly) has the same question as you. You seem not to be the onlyone with issues related to that card. But they should be corrected already.

Comment: I found a driver at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi   It seems to have fixed the problem except Firefox now crashes when I connect wireless but doesn't when I connect wired.  The next hill to climb.

Comment: I never heard of a crashing browser caused by a malfunctioning ethernet device. 
Did you try some other browser like iceweasel or google chrome, to see if the problem presists?

Comment: I just installed chromium and it works perfectly.  I do not intend to use the device with a browser so all I care is that the wireless is working.  Thanks for your suggestion.